# Jquery Unable to select and deselect a td on clicking it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have written 2 jquery functions. Lines 1-11 is the first one which binds mouseover event on mousedown to get the effect of click and drag to select td's(internally checking/unchecking checkboxes).

Second function(12-20) is to click and unclick on single td to check and uncheck a checkbox. I am able to do mousedown and select multiple td's but I am not able to a click and unclick on single td. I am not sure where the problem is ? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
$("#tbl td").mousedown(function() {
    $("#tbl td").bind('mouseover', function() {
        var checkbox = $(':checkbox', this)[0];
        $(this).css({
            'background': (checkbox.checked ? 'white' : '#6D7B8D')
        });
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    });
    $(this).mouseover();
}).mouseup(function(event) {
    $("#td").unbind('mouseover');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#tbl td').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "");
        $(this).css({
            background: "white"
        });
    } else {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", "checked");
        $(this).css({
            background: "#6D7B8D"
        });
    }
});​
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the behavior?  For example, when you say that `I am not able to a click and unclick on single td`, are you getting inside of that `click()` function?

Comment: You are preventing the default behavior in the mouseup handler. I think that it is probably overriding the click functionality.

Comment: Maybe an example of the HTML this is used for will help, and a little off topic, but you should be using `[type="checkbox"]`, your `css()` function is faulty, it's supposed to have a comma as a seperator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if this is what you exactly need but maybe could help.

***(Just to know, it will be really helpful if you put the HTML code!)***

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/TATg7/

**Code:**

```
$('#tbl').on('mousedown, mouseover, mouseup, click', 'td', function(e) {
    if(e.type == 'mousedown'){
        $(this).mouseover();
    } else if(e.type == 'mouseover'){
        var checkbox = $('input:checkbox');
        $(this).css({'background': (checkbox.is(':checked') ? 'white' : '#6D7B8D')});
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.checked);    
    } else if(e.type == 'mouseup'){
        $(this).unbind('mouseover');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else if(e.type == 'click'){
        var checked = $('input:checked').is(':checked');
        checked ? background = 'white' : background = '#6D7B8D';
        $('input:checked').prop('checked', !checked);
        $(this).css({background: background});
    }
});
​
```

Comment: Well.. the issue here is when I click on a td, it goes inside mousedown and inside mouseover also inside click. But When I click on a single td I dont want the control to go to mousedown and mouseover..

Comment: Sure.. Actually my Html also has PHP code it it.                            <tr class="data-row">        
                      <?php for($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; ++$hour): ?>
                <td id="tbl-data" class="data" width="10">
<label for="<?=$short?>_<?=$hour?>"><input type="checkbox" id="<?=$short?>_<?=$hour?>" name="tbl[<?=$short?>][<?=$hour?>]" value="<?=$hour?>" <?=isset($tbl[$short][$hour]) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> style="display:none"/></label>
                </td>
                      <?php endfor; ?>
                </tr>

Comment: I tried your solution , I get $("#tbl").on is not a function when I execute the code

Comment: Let me try something with your HTML code. Well, just to know on(); function exists from jQuery version 1.6.x and upper and my example is using version 1.7.2 :-)

Comment: I found out the real problem, which is I have 4 events mousedown, mouseover, mouseup and click. what is happening is when I try to click, I will press my mouse down which triggers mousedown first and mouseover and mouseup and in the last click would get called. I need to put an if condition such that If I click then do not go to mousedown function.

Comment: Oh! my version of jquery is 1.4.x